# Visualforce Insufficient Privilges for user.Profile.Name on column tag

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page that I am displaying some user information for a community administration page.

In my controller I am querying (among several other fields):

```
Select UserName, FirstName, LastName, Profile.Name From User
```

In my VF page I am getting the following error,

> **Insufficient Privileges**
>   You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

with the following VF snippet:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!inactiveUsers}" var="user">
    <apex:column value="{!user.FirstName}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!user.LastName}"/>
    ...
    <apex:column headerValue="Permissions" value="{!user.Profile.Name}"/>
```

Yet, if I do this:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Permissions">
    <apex:outputText value="{!user.Profile.Name}"/>
</apex:column>
```

It works fine. I am confused as to why this is???

Comment: Is it because the user.profile.name and other user.profile fields is public by default while the user.FirstName and User.LastName are restricted by the User object security settings. Isn't the user.profile for the chatter profile so needs to be public?

Comment: Do you want to show details of the logged in User or some other user?

Comment: The user variable is for a list of users that are a part of a certain community, the logged in user is a part of that subset as well.